# How to use wordpress and Laravel together?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, laravel

I have a large custom form with all HTML, JS and CSS ready in one page of a custom Wordpress site.

I would like to use Laravel's framework to handle the server side validation and db operations to maintain the form data. I'm currently using plain old PHP to do this and PDO for db operations which doesn't feel tidy.

Please let me know How can I can handle my custom form in a WP site with Laravel?
I have a separate MySQL DB for form's submission data from the WP site database.

Comment: May be I'm wrong, but it's a bad idea.

Comment: Ok so should I stick with plain old php?

Comment: It does not nessesary to stick with plain old php. To validate input you can use standalone library, like https://github.com/Respect/Validation.

Comment: Thanks! But how do I use the validation engine with the submitted data in the php files? I have not installed a package with composer before.

Comment: so learn how composer works :) But you definetely don't need to use whole Laravel framework just to validate input.

Comment: Sure but I believe using the Laravel framework will be useful in maintaining the and modularising the code more efficiently. It also provides good DB access using DAL classes? I'm not going for Laravel just because I need to validate input.

Comment: Just wondering if the effort to use WP with Laravel for my form will be worth it? Will using Laravel provide more benefit than just form server side validation.